# PHP - Getting data from XML feed

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have the following code:

```
<?php

  $url = 'http://www.floatrates.com/daily/gbp.xml';
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("feed not loading");

  foreach ($xml as $val) {
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($val) . "</pre>";
  }

?>
```

Which outputs loads of these (1 per currency) :

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [title] => 1 GBP = 1.39687377 USD [link] => http://www.floatrates.com/gbp/usd/ [description] => 1 U.K. Pound Sterling = 1.39687377 U.S. Dollar [pubDate] => Mon, 29 Feb 2016 00:00:01 GMT [baseCurrency] => GBP [baseName] => U.K. Pound Sterling [targetCurrency] => USD [targetName] => U.S. Dollar [exchangeRate] => 1.39687377 )
```

How do I grab only the USD one? And then extract the exchange rate?

I've tried

```
if ($val['targetCurrency'] == "USD") {
}
```

But that doesn't work for now

Comment: [See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) for an example of basic usage

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the link from Robbie:

```
if ($val->targetCurrency == "USD") {
  echo $val->exchangeRate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use XPath for doing this

```
$url = 'http://www.floatrates.com/daily/gbp.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("feed not loading");

$results = $xml->xpath('/channel/item/targetCurrency[.="USD"]/following-sibling::exchangeRate');

$exchangeRate = (float)$results[0];
```